# Accurately remove whitespace introduced by footer on only the first page

Tags: xetex, formatting, margins, geometry

I have a document that has text that very nearly reaches the limits of the page geometry (the document has one centimeter margins). I have a footer (using `fancyhdr`) on all pages except the first by using

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

at the beginning of my document. I have allocated space for the footer by defining the `geometry` to be

```
% Set the margins
\usepackage[
    left   = 1cm,
    right  = 1cm,
    top    = 1cm,
    bottom = 1cm,
    includefoot  % Include space for a footer
]{geometry}
```

(with `includefoot`). I find this works very well and keeps the document clean. However, the `geometry` options are applied to all pages, including the first. I would not like there to be whitespace between the text and the page margin on the first page of the document (in other words, the text should continue until only the 1cm margin remains with no additional space).

My options are limited because I do not know where the content on the first page will end, so I cannot wrap the text and apply changes directly. I also do not know the height of the footer (which is why I pass `includefoot` to the `geometry` package).

Is this modification feasible? Can it be done in a robust manner (even as the contents of the document change)? I appreciate any ideas!

Comment: Fancyhdr is notorious for changing the page geometry after the first page if the default sizes are not big enough.  Just make sure you reserve enough space for \headheight (max 1cm-\headsep) and \footskip (max 1cm) using geometry.  You can measure the footer height in the preamble using a savebox.